# GCD in several polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p(x)=x^6-1$ over which <strike>group</strike> field is true that $\gcd(p(x),p'(x)) \neq 1$ . The <strike>groups</strike> fields are:

$K = \mathbb{Q}$

I have calculated the gcd = $-6x^5$, so it is not the correct answer.

$K = \mathbb{Z}_3$

Here, $p'(x) = 0$ so the gcd = 1.

$K = \mathbb{Z}_5$

Again, I have calculated the gcd = $-x^5$, so it is not the correct answer.

$K = \mathbb{Z}_7$

I have the same result that in $K = \mathbb{Z}_5$

Someone can help me please?

Comment: is this an abstract algebra question?

Comment: Yes the algebra is abstract

Comment: You have problems with calculating the gcd, and the concept of a factor in general. 1) For example, do you understand why $0$ is divisible by everything? 2) Are you saying that $-6x^5$ is a factor of $x^6-1$? I would think not! No matter what polynomial you multiply $-6x^5$ with, you are not going to introduce a non-zero constant term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greatest common divisor of $x^6-1$ and $6x^5$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $-6x^5$! $c=\gcd(a,b)$ means $c|a$ and $c|b$. But root of $-6x^5$ are all zero, which means $(x^6-1,6x^5)=1$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

In $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $p'(x)=0$, thus the greatest common divisor is exactly $x^6-1$ since $0$ is multiple of any element.

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, with similar argument in $\mathbb{Q}$, since all roots of $6x^5$ are $0$, we know that the greatest common divisor is also $1$, the same holds in $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Comment: When you say $\mathbb{C}$ you want to say $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @rgl4 Yes, thanks for pointing out.